# Dask Worker Process Memory Keeps Growing

Tags: tensorflow, dask-distributed

I am optimizing ML models on a dask distributed, tensorflow, keras set up. 
Worker processes keep growing in memory.

Tensorflow uses CPUs of 25 nodes. Each node have about 3 worker process.

Each task takes about 20 seconds.

I don't want to restart every time memory is full because this makes the operation stop for a while, causing delays.

I am using client.cancel() after .gather() but had no effect. I do gc.collect() inside the task but had also no effect.

The only solution is to restart worker processes.

Anyone have other solutions?

Dask distributed version: 1.21.1
Python: 3.6.3
Tensorflow: 1.7
Keras: 2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Keras (Tensorflow) needed to be cleared.

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```